# sfmc sql query to update a data extension field using using like function in the same data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sfmcadmin

I am working on a slightly complex scenario and need your help figuring out the correct approach. I have data extension contains 3 columns (product family, product code, product description) each family of products have submodels that are provided in the description field.
for example product xx basic, xx pro, xx ultimate.
im trying to write a query using LIKE function that searches for xx in the description field and updates the family field on the same data extension.

it would look like something like below:

```
product family| product code | product description
--------------------------------------------------
xx            | XXP502       | XX basic plan
--------------------------------------------------
xx            | XXP512       | XX pro plan
--------------------------------------------------
xx            | XXP522       | XX ultimate plan
```

im new to sfmc sql and would really appreciate it if you can help me write this.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you may want to try to use Excel sheet to process the data instead of SQL since somehow I think it might be faster.

In SQL, you should create a separate DE first then use SQL query to populate data into this DE.

Use CASE expression in SQL to return a value based on conditions.

For product family name: my idea would be I use CHARINDEX to find the index of the product plan, then get the product family name by using SUBSTRING

For product code: it would be the same like the way for product family name, but concentrate with product code (corresponding with its product plan?)

```SQL
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('basic plan', [product description]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([product description], 1, CHARINDEX('basic plan', [product description]) -2)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('pro plan', [product description]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([product description], 1, CHARINDEX('pro plan', [product description]) -2)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('ultimate plan', [product description]) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING([product description], 1, CHARINDEX('ultimate plan', [product description]) -2)
END AS [product family],
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('basic plan', [product description]) > 0 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING([product description], 1, CHARINDEX('basic plan', [product description]) -2), 'P502')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('pro plan', [product description]) > 0 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING([product description], 1, CHARINDEX('pro plan', [product description]) -2), 'P512')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('ultimate plan', [product description]) > 0 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING([product description], 1, CHARINDEX('ultimate plan', [product description]) -2), 'P522')
END AS [product code],
[product description]
FROM
[DE name]
```

References:

- [CASE expression](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)
- [CHARINDEX function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp)
- [CONCAT function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp)
- [SUBSTRING function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do a simple string replacement on `product description` to isolate the `product family` values?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products
    ([product code] varchar(50), [product description] varchar(100))
;
INSERT INTO Products
     ([product code], [product description])
VALUES
 ('XXP502','XX basic plan')
,('XXP512','XX pro plan')
,('XXP522','XX ultimate plan')
```

```sql
select
  ltrim(replace(replace(replace(p.[product description],'basic plan',''),'pro plan',''),'ultimate plan','')) [product family]
, [product code]
, [product description]
from Products p
```

Output:

| product family | product code | product description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XX | XXP502 | XX basic plan |
| XX | XXP512 | XX pro plan |
| XX | XXP522 | XX ultimate plan |

Try it yourself: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uV_mKQkv)

Comment: It looks more elegant to me :) If the product code column need to be populated also, what would you do?